# How to center nav on top of fixed the image?

Tags: css

This code works perfect for aligning nav to the right, but when I try to center and give some margin to the top, image is moving together with nav. How to fix this problem?

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <div class="row">
            <ul class="main-nav">
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}    

.row {
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
    background-image: url(img/01.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.main-nav {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 60px;
}

.main-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

I would like to center main-nav and give margin:60px without giving margin to the background image.

Comment: What image? And what did you do to "center and give some margin to the top"? Please include the minimal amount of code needed to replicate the current behavior. See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry, that was my first post in here.

Answer (score 0):

That's called margin collapse - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

> If there is no border, padding, inline content, block_formatting_context created or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block from the margin-top of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block from the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

You can fix it with any of those methods. In this case, I would just add padding to the top of `header` instead of a top margin on `.main-nav`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background-image: url(http://cdn.thedailybeast.com/content/dailybeast/articles/2015/03/31/neil-degrasse-tyson-defends-scientology-and-the-bush-administration-s-science-record/jcr:content/image.img.2000.jpg/1432067001553.cached.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.main-nav {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.main-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav>
        <div class="row">
            <ul class="main-nav">
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```